# YayraBox Datatables JavaScript CDN conflicts with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, datatables

I am a beginner learning Laravel.

I have been including bootstrap and general css and js in my templates:

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

I have added the CDN for the jquery and jquery-datatables library but I now get an error.

To make it work, I have commented out `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` which is compiled by the Laravel app and means I lose any custom JavaScript that I had.

```html
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
              crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> -->

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Why do these Libraries conflict with the Laravel app and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel app.js already contains jquery.js, so you do not need to add that again, so Yjra table js, should be added just below app.js like

```
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Try to keep all JS in footer section, now for css, too, you just need to add the css just below app.css

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

even I have one repository, you can follow [here](https://github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/yajraapp/blob/master/resources/views/displaydata.blade.php).

Comment: Thank you. I have it working with the CDNs, how can I get the asssets working?

Comment: @GlenUK You can download the script and css and put it in `public/js` and `public/css` folder respectively and then you can use above code to make it work.